# Not correct scope for accessing events

Tags: django, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, python-social-auth

> HttpError at /calendar
> <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/calendar
> Django Version: 3.2.9
> Exception Type: HttpError
> Exception Value:

Then does this after a while

> RefreshError at /calendar
> The credentials do not contain the necessary fields need to refresh the access token. You must specify refresh_token, token_uri, client_id, and client_secret.

It seems I don't possess the right scope when accessing the calendar and it seems currently the access_token does appear.

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
def get_user_events(request):
    credentials = Credentials(get_access_token(request), scopes=SCOPES)
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    google_calendar_events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    google_calendar_events = google_calendar_events.get('items', [])
    return google_calendar_events

def get_access_token(request): 
    social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2') 
    return social.extra_data['access_token']
```

So the Scope I am using is the following

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
```

Comment: What scopes are you using for this and how does the `access_token` token look like - do you have the needed fields for this? Have you considered the answer provided already, if so, does it work for your use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.".

If we check the documentation for [events.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get) we will find that this method operates on private user data which means that we need to be authorized to access it.  On top of that we need to be authorized with one of the following scopes

[image]

I cant see from your code which scopes you are requesting.  The first thing to do is to ensure that you are requesting one of the scopes above when authorizing your user.   If you change the scopes remember you must request consent of the user again for it to take effect.

> You must specify refresh_token, token_uri, client_id, and client_secret.

Sounds like you are not properly storing your refresh token. get_access_token wont work if it doesn't have a refresh token stored.

In the official sample notice how they store the user creds in token.json then the library will automatically request a new access token when it needs.

```
 """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

Comment: So I added the scope I put this into my view . Then I tried to run it got a credentials not found then used a Oauth 2.0 client json file for the credentials and then ran into a redirect uri mismatch from another url. Is that the proper procedure so far. Say like my landing page is url.com I want this accessed from url.com/calendar

Comment: Yes its for an InstalledAppFlow.  I am not aware of any samples for [web flow](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/cbb1f88b82b21f5cb9dcace33ffea3f95a189015/docs/oauth.md) with this library  i have always assumed it was not supported.